# How can I trigger a build in Jenkins on a Pull Request Merge event and ignore commits from a specific user?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, webhooks, pull-request

I am documenting my own experience, it has been long and wory but worth it, CI/CD gets more complex as our development teams mature, and we as DevOps need to act consequently, I have found a lack of clear simple instructions on how to achieve this sort of thing, so I am sharing my steps on the hope I could save some others valuable time to focus on important details rather than on implementation details. Unfortunately we have many moving pieces involving at least one sort of Source Code Management Tool (GitHub or BitBucket or others) and our CI/CD tool (in this case Jenkins), the following is based on a Github Repository with webhooks that trigger on a Jenkins server using the plugin `generic-webhook-trigger-plugin`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I will start on the SCM side (Github), we have a repo, we need to go into the repo and configure the hooks

[image]

As I am using the jenkins plugin `generic-webhook-trigger-plugin` I will set this webhook to call the specific endpoint for it:

`https://myjenkins.com/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=AAABBBCCC`

And it looks something like this:[image: Payload must be JSON]

Then we can go to Jenkins I am assuming you already have a running Jenkins server with the `generic-webhook-trigger` plugin installed, so I am going to focus on how to configure a Jenkins Job:

My job configuration (the relevant part for this to work) looks like this:
[image]

And this is how my Job Looks Like, basically it will IGNORE all the commits made by a user with name "Jenkins" you can adjust this depending on your payload.

where
$.commits[0].committer.name = "Jenkins" and this is how GitHub webhook deliver's the payload.

$COMMITTER is the variable defined in the Post content parameters section

And the most important part:

`^((?!jenkins).)*$` which is the regular expression that evaluates negatively to exclude that jenkins user

It could be extended to more users like this:
`^((?!jenkins|anotherUser).)*$`

**UPDATE**: Since we are Tagging as well as Pushing, the payloads are different on each call, so you need to set the `expression` part of the post content parameters as:

`$.head_commit.committer.name` instead of `$.commits[0].committer.name`

Answer (score 0):

There is a part that I missed, the Pull Request Merge Logic, this is obviously pretty specific to a workflow and awfully common, so the logic that will drive this is that you need to restrict on you SCM (in my case github) that merges should only be done to specific branches using Pull Requests.

I am using as well single trunk development, so I have a `development` branch and that is the one I set upon the restrictions, My webhook is configured in consequence to react to push events on that branch, thus triggering the hook and hopefully the Jenkins build.

The limitation on specific users, it is when you for whatever reason need to commit from the job changes to your repository, in my case I update the version of the artifact being built, the whole idea of this setup is to avoid infinite loop scenarios where you have the trigger that commits directly to your branch thus the trigger start a build, the build commits to the repo thus triggering another build, so on and forth.

It is important to point out that Jenkins user (a service account in my case) has the rights to commit directly to develop without a Pull request so it can push the tag and changes that tie with the artifact version.

Regards.

EN